# How to a python script run on any computer

Tags: python

How to a python file run on any computer as I have to install python every time to get it to run on some new computer.

For example I file called foo.py

```
print("this should run on any computer")
```

How do I run this on anyone's computer?

Comment: You can't have it run on ANY computer.  You can use tools like `pyinstaller` to turn your Python script into an executable, but that only works on machines with the same operating system.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use a program called pyinstaller to convert the py file to a exe file which can run on any computer.

Comment: This creates OS-specific packages, so it doesn't quite let you run it on *any* computer.

Comment: Also, simply pointing out the existence of `pyinstaller` does not really make for a good answer to a question.